# How to read list of strings saved via Flutter shared_preferences on the native Android side?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin to save list of strings to Shared Preferences. When trying to read it on the Android side using `getStringSet` it fails with `ClassCastException`. How can I read the list of strings saved via shared_preferences in Flutter in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `shared_preferences` plugin uses its custom encoding to save list of strings as string. You cannot read it using Android's `getStringSet`.

In order to read and decode it on the Android side you can adapt their [ListEncoder](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/a757073ac4eaf05b7516d3d0488e5c98b221043f/packages/shared_preferences/shared_preferences_android/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/sharedpreferences/SharedPreferencesPlugin.java#L188):

```
internal class ListEncoder  {
    private val LIST_IDENTIFIER = "VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgcHJlZml4IGZvciBhIGxpc3Qu"

    fun decode(listString: String?): List<String> {
        return try {
            if (listString != null){
                val stringValue = listString.substring(LIST_IDENTIFIER.length)
                val stream = ObjectInputStream(ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(stringValue, 0)))
                stream.readObject() as List<String>
            } else {
                emptyList()
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        } catch (e: ClassNotFoundException) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

And later you can use it as follows:

```
    fun readStringList(key: String) : List<String> {
        try {
            val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences()

            val list = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
            if (list != null){
                val encoder = ListEncoder()
                return encoder.decode(list)
            }
            return emptyList();
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return emptyList()
        }
    }
```

Make sure to add `flutter.` prefix to the `key` as Flutter's shared_preferences use it by default when saving data to Shared Preferences.